# division encountered NA value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame and I need to process two columns, let's say `A` and `B`.

Col `B` has some `"NA"` rows in it. I was trying this:

```
df['ratio']= (df['A']/loan_data_df['B'].astype(int)).where(loan_data_df['B']!= 'NA')
```

but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try replacing 'NA' with `np.nan`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need replace `NA` string to `NaN` ([missing value](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html)) and then use [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) with parameter `fill_value` for replace to `1` for prevent `NaN` like in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45940800/2901002):

```
df['ratio']= df['A'].div(df['B'].replace('NA', np.nan).astype(float), fill_value=1)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[4,2,3],
                   'B':['NA','4','5']})

df['ratio']= df['A'].div(df['B'].replace('NA', np.nan).astype(float), fill_value=1)
print (df)
   A   B  ratio
0  4  NA    4.0
1  2   4    0.5
2  3   5    0.6
```

If no `NaN` only `NA` values:

```
df['ratio']= df['A'].div(df['B'].replace('NA',1).astype(float))
print (df)
   A   B  ratio
0  4  NA    4.0
1  2   4    0.5
2  3   5    0.6
```

But mainly it depends of your data, maybe is necessary only:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[4,2,3],
                   'B':[np.nan,4,5]})

df['ratio']= df['A'].div(df['B'], fill_value=1)
print (df)
           A    B  ratio
0  4  NaN    4.0
1  2  4.0    0.5
2  3  5.0    0.6
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, i tried it and it worked!

Comment: glad can help, nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to replace the 'NA' with `np.nan`, for that you can try:

```
df = df.fillna(np.nan)
```

Then Pandas will put nan wherever the division is invalid.

```
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> import  numpy as np 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 3, 5, 29], "B": [5, 4, 44, np.nan]})
>>> df
    A     B
0   1   5.0
1   3   4.0
2   5  44.0
3  29   NaN
>>> df["A"]/df["B"]
0    0.200000
1    0.750000
2    0.113636
3         NaN
dtype: float64
>>> df["ratio"] = df["A"]/df["B"]
>>> df
    A     B     ratio
0   1   5.0  0.200000
1   3   4.0  0.750000
2   5  44.0  0.113636
3  29   NaN       NaN
>>>
```